# Filtering postmeta based on a specific meta_ key and meta_value

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have the following SQL statement to calculate several fields based on 3 Wordpress tables. What I need is to include only results where meta_key='odd' and meta_value >= '1.5'. I tried in the WHERE statement but it doesn't work as most results in this query appear as Null.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
SELECT (display_name) AS 'user',
    SUM(Case When meta_key = 'status' Then meta_value = 'won' else Null End) AS 'Won',
    SUM(Case When meta_key = 'status' Then meta_value = 'lost' else Null End) AS 'Lost',
    COUNT(Case When meta_key = 'odd' Then meta_value else Null End) AS 'Total',
    ROUND (AVG(Case When meta_key = 'odd' Then meta_value else Null End), 2) AS 'Avg odd',
    ROUND (AVG(Case When meta_key = 'bet' Then meta_value else Null End), 2) AS 'Avg bet',
    ROUND (SUM(Case When meta_key = 'balance' Then meta_value else Null End), 2) AS 'Balance'
FROM wp_postmeta pm
INNER JOIN wp_posts p ON pm.post_id = p.ID 
INNER JOIN wp_users u ON p.post_author = u.ID
WHERE Month(post_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) AND p.post_status='publish' AND pm.meta_key='odd' AND pm.met.value >='1.5'
GROUP BY (display_name)
ORDER BY Balance DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move this to a `having` clause:

```
SELECT (display_name) AS 'user',
    SUM(Case When meta_key = 'status' Then meta_value = 'won' else Null End) AS 'Won',
    SUM(Case When meta_key = 'status' Then meta_value = 'lost' else Null End) AS 'Lost',
    COUNT(Case When meta_key = 'odd' Then meta_value else Null End) AS 'Total',
    ROUND (AVG(Case When meta_key = 'odd' Then meta_value else Null End), 2) AS 'Avg odd',
    ROUND (AVG(Case When meta_key = 'bet' Then meta_value else Null End), 2) AS 'Avg bet',
    ROUND (SUM(Case When meta_key = 'balance' Then meta_value else Null End), 2) AS 'Balance'
FROM wp_postmeta pm
INNER JOIN wp_posts p ON pm.post_id = p.ID 
INNER JOIN wp_users u ON p.post_author = u.ID
WHERE Month(post_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) AND p.post_status='publish' 
GROUP BY (display_name)
having SUM(case when pm.meta_key='odd' AND pm.meta_value >='1.5' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
ORDER BY Balance DESC
```

This determines whether such a row exists for each `display_name`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still doesn't work, now it shows results for every meta_value even if it's less than 1.5, so it's not filtering the results. Do you have any idea why? Thanks

Comment: @qebus . . . How is meta_value stored?  Is it a character string or numeric?